# Can't see NAS in Virtual Machine on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-machine

I have windows 7 64 bit with Windows Virtual Machine software installed.
On the virtual machine you cannot see the the network and in particular the QNAP nas connected but in win 7 you can.
What can I do so that in the Virtual machine you can see the NAS?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is the IP address assigned to the guest OS.  If the guest OS IP address ***isn't*** on the same network range as the host, the guest OS network adapter may be connected to the host OS only or on a virtual network.  If the guest OS IP address ***is*** in the same network range as your host network, I would see if I can ping the host OS and the NAS.  Unless you have some firewall software running, everything should be pingable.  If you can't ping other machines from the guest OS, I would look at any firewall software you have installed on both the host and guest OS.  The host security software could be blocking the new IP address that virtual machine is registering.

If at that point you still can't get the guest OS to communicate to the NAS, the NAS may have a white list of IP addresses that are allowed to communicate with it.  If so, the guest OS's IP address needs to be added or that restriction lifted.

As a side note, I use VMware, and I'm not sure what software you are using, but most virtualization software have a concept of having the network adapter in Bridge mode.  Bridge mode means it would appears just as another computer on the network would look.  I would ensure the network adapter is set to Bridge mode, but if it was set to NAT mode that wouldn't prohibit outbound communications.

Sorry about the long winded reply, but it is hard to give more specific advice without knowing more about how things are configured.

I hope these tips help and good luck.